# Why order by not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have the following query:

```
select DISTINCT CASE WHEN msg_from = 35 
    then msg_to else msg_from 
end msg_from_result , msg_id,msg_from,msg_to,msg_content,msg_status,msg_created_at,
    (select user_name from users where user_id = msg_from_result) user_name
    from messages 
    where 35 in (msg_from , msg_to) 
group by msg_from_result 
    order by msg_id desc
```

This should retrieve the conversations with the last message belonging to it.
The conversations are retrieved, but the problem here is I can't use the `ORDER BY` to get the last msg by setting `ORDER BY msg_id DESC`.

What's wrong with this? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. When there is a GROUP BY you can only SELECT columns in it or aggregations of columns or (since a recent version of MySQL) columns that are functionally dependent on it. Read the documentation for GROUP BY.

Comment: you are right, I forget that, anyway even if I correct the statement I'll not get the correct results , could u please help if u understand my question.

Comment: First write a query to SELECT a key & the MAX message time per group when GROUPing BY the key. Then you JOIN that (or use IN) to get conversations with that MAX message time. PS If you want to come up with queries more easily, write a sentence template parameterized by column names (ie a *predicate*) that is made true by rows in the table and false by rows not in the table. For a query like this you will find yourself writing that the outer query SELECTs "... message MSG_ID is equal to the MSG_ID of the message whose MSG_ CREATED_AT is the MAX of ... " and there a join or subquery turns up.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you're trying to do, but here's how I'd write it (if I'm understanding correctly):

```
select users.user_name, msg_id, msg_from, msg_to, msg_content, msg_status, msg_created_at
from (
select if(msg_from = 35,msg_to,msg_from) as msg_from_result
, max(msg_id) as last_message
from messages 
where 35 in (msg_from,msg_to) 
group by msg_from_result,last_message
) der_table -- creating a table of conversations and the last message ids
join users on user_id=der_table.msg_from_result
join messages on messages.msg_id=der_table.last_message
order by msg_id desc
```

You need to get the last message ID before you can get the message's content etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you want (I think) is a correlated subquery.  The results of the outer query are restricted by truth of a predicate in the subquery.  In your case, you want information about the last `msg_id`.

Having answered this question in different forms many times, I wrote [a simple example](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#first.of.n).   Based on what you have so far, I think you'll be able to translate that into your particular query.  It will look something like

```
where exists ( 
    select 1 from messages
    where outer.msg_id = msg_id
    group by msg_id
    having outer.msg_id = max(msg_id)
)
```